# Grunt plugins not found using load-grunt-config

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, browser-sync

I've split out my grunt plugins into their own files and I'm using the load-grunt-config (https://github.com/firstandthird/load-grunt-config) to call them:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  'use strict';

  require('load-grunt-config')(grunt);
};
```

I've got sass, autoprefixer, cssmin and watch tasks working but I'm also using Browsersync and px-to-rem these two plugins return:

```
Warning: Task "remify" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

and

```
Warning: Task "browsersync" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

when called individually or as part of a bigger task.

I've followed the syntax for the separate.js files for these two plugin so I'm at a loss. For example the remify.js file which is called when running grunt is written like this

```
module.exports = {
  dist: {
    options: {
      base: 16,
      fallback: true,
      fallback_existing_rem: true,
      ignore: []
    },
    files: {
      'css/style.css': 'css/style.css'
    }
  }
};
```

Any ideas where this is going wrong?

I've also set up a gist of the example code, include package.json and a aliases.yml

https://gist.github.com/sturobson/f88258fd010e901e24d9

Answer (score 3):

You have to call the grunt plugin *exactly* what it is. So where I've got `remify` I should be using `px_to_rem` and where I've got `browsersync` and I should have `browserSync`.

Silly me.

Answer (score 3):

you can pass a second argument to `load-grunt-config` to provide some options where you could also define some pattern which can be used by [load-grunt-tasks](https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-grunt-tasks) which is used internally.

if you don't pass a second argument, it uses the default-pattern of [load-grunt-tasks](https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-grunt-tasks) which is `grunt-*`.

so if you want to load all devDependencies without defining them seperatly, do it like this:

```
require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
    loadGruntTasks: {
        pattern: '*',
        scope: 'devDependencies'
    }
});
```